# Easiest way to broadcast events to siblings in the render tree?

Tags: famo.us

The basic structure of views
AppView > PageView > XView, YView, ZView.

Where ">" is a "has a" association. How can one easily broadcast event from ZView to its other siblings XView and YView

Thanks

Comment: Just for clarification do you mean you are nesting the views that far or do you mean like one view calls the next view calls the next view? Maybe AppView can call Page View that can call any of the three XYZViews?

Comment: Yes I am nesting them. So if ZView has a InputSurface which for which there is a keyboard event, I would like YView to listen to it as well. Do I listen at PageView and emit back so YView can listen again or is there better way?

Comment: My explanation of what i did was long the gist was for me I just sent the event to the parent then had it call functions on the rest of them that activated any change that needed to be made because of the event.

Comment: I am new to the the framework. But it might be easier to do this for certain use cases using EventArbiter  EventArbiter is a way to route events based on a 
 particular mode.  Each mode can have at most one
 event handler that handles the events when the 
 EventArbiter is in that mode.